# Jersey REST Service - 404 response in Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jaxb, jersey

I have a Jersey service that I installed on one machine and worked perfectly, then I imported the project on another machine, created a WAR and deployed it in tomcat 6.0.

But now it returns a `404`.

The source code is in the following link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

I have no clue where to start looking for problems. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I would start by figuring out what the difference is between the two projects. Try unzipping both WARs and comparing the structure.

Comment: Can you at least paste the log ...There should be some hint int the log file why this is not working

Comment: Joining to @mvlupan comment, I suggest you'll go through the tomcat log (catalina.out) and search for errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Its a wild guess. But I am almost sure it is happening because you dont have jersey.jar in the classpath. I am guessng this because I think as you do not have the jar in the classpath when the container is seeimg something like rest/* in the URL it is searching for the  Jersey Servlet ; which being not in the class path is not found. Hence the error